# Loading logs from Google Cloud Storage bucket into BigQuery

Tags: logging, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

My goal is to get all my (GCS created) logs from Google Cloud Storage into BigQuery, using the BigQuery web interface.
Since logs are created hourly I like to import them all at once to analyze.

So for example gs://logging-bucket/images.mysite.net_storage_2013_03_31_07_00_00_0001a_v0 , gs://logging-bucket/images.mysite.net_storage_2013_03_31_07_00_00_0002a_v0 and so on.

I get this error when getting just one file:

Errors:

```
 Line:1 / Column:1, Expected '{' found '"'
 Line:2 / Column:1, Expected '{' found '"' 
 Line:3 / Column:1, Expected '{' found '"'
 Line:4 / Column:1, Expected '{' found '"'
 Line:5 / Column:1, Expected '{' found '"'
 Line:6 / Column:1, Expected '{' found '"'
 Line:7 / Column:1, Expected '{' found '"'
```

What I did is create a new dataset, selected data from gs://logging-bucket/images.mysite.net_storage_2013_03_31_07_00_00_0001a_v0 then added this schema http://storage.googleapis.com/pub/cloud_storage_usage_schema_v0.json and submitted this.

Similar questions on here and Google ing this didn't help me a lot.

Please, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give an example of a row?  Is the data in json format or csv? From the error, it sounds like it is trying to import JSON data, but a json row shouldn't start with '"' -- it should start with '{'. Is this CSV data? If so, you should set the sourceFormat to CSV (or leave it empty) instead of NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON.